# Must max(field1) within max(field2) use an inner join?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I wish to find the maximum value of a field (tradeId, but cast as a Long) within the maximum value of another field (timestamp).

I have the following HQL query which works fine, and is quick, but I wonder if joining a table to itself it really the most elegant way of achieving this? EXPLAIN tells me that "select tables optimized away", so maybe not?

```
@Query("select max(cast(t1.tradeId as long)) from TradeDbo t1 inner join TradeDbo t2 on t1.id = t2.id"
       +" where t2.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from TradeDbo where currencyPair.id = :currencyPairId)")
```

The TradeDbo class:

```
public class TradeDbo extends Auditable<String> {
  @Id @GeneratedValue   
  @Getter private Long id;

  @JoinColumn(name = "currency_pair_id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
  @Getter private CurrencyPairDbo currencyPair;

  @Column(name = "timestamp")
  @Convert(converter = DateConverter.class)
  @Getter private Date timestamp;

  @Column(name = "trade_id")
  @Getter private String tradeId;
  ...
```

The SQL generated by the HQL is:

```
select max(cast(tradedbo0_.trade_id as signed)) as col_0_0_ from trade tradedbo0_ 
inner join trade tradedbo1_ on (tradedbo0_.id=tradedbo1_.id) 
where tradedbo1_.timestamp=(select max(tradedbo2_.timestamp) 
from trade tradedbo2_ where tradedbo2_.currency_pair_id=21185903)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: you refer to a  table `currencyPair` not mention in from and join clause.. explain better please ..and you are using an unuseful duplication for TradeDbo  value  .. from TradeDbo t1 inner join TradeDbo t2 on t1.id = t2.id  is the same  .. as TradeDbo.id

Comment: @scaisEdge  Yes, it's curious that works.  I can only imagine that within the embedded select clause the fields require no qualification.  I'll add the TrdadeDbo definition

Comment: are you sure  ?   .. could be that there is an error and you don't see .. try change @query with $query ..

Comment: @scaisEdge: I've added the generated SQL as well: it's used a third qualification for TradeDbo

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid repeated  join on the same table

```
select max(cast(trade_id as signed)) as col_0_0_ 
from trade 
INNER JOIN (
    select max(timestamp)  max_value
    from tradewhere currency_pair_id=21185903
) t on t.max_value = trade.timestamp
```